# WPF - Add a taskbar button programmatically inside OnStartup call

Tags: c#, wpf, startup, taskbar

In WPF, is it possible to display taskbar button programmatically while code is executing inside OnStartup (Before any window creation).

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var context = e.Args.FirstOrDefault();
    if (null == context)
    {
        //Show the App in taskbar, otherwise if user click another window, this msgbox will be hidden

        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("View name is not supplied. Exiting application", "Wrong parameters", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        Environment.Exit(0);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried on "adding taskbar custom button" so far.

Comment: If I use windows messagebox, I can call like this, MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information, MessageBoxResult.OK, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);

Comment: But now I am using Xceed MessageBox, so MessageBoxOptions is not available.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what's the difference when using `MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification` instead of sticking with the default options in a WPF application...

Comment: @grek40, my requirement is to show a task bar button when displaying a messagebox. I am doing this inside OnStartup and there is no window formed yet. When I was using WPF provided message box(MessageBox.Show) with 6 parameters, it comes with default windows button on taskbar. But when I use Xceed provided messagebox(Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show), it is not having any button. So I am asking, is there any way I can create a button first, then attach that button to Dialogbox, so that my users need not have to struggle to find the UI from all windows instead they can click taskbar.